# jqgrid not passing search filter data type on refresh of grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

When loadig the grid for the first time the json data that gets sent to my search method on the server for the filter property has a value of:

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"ModifiedBy","op":"cn","data":"SomeData","type":"text"}]}
```

But when I click the refresh button on the jqgrid the json data for the filter property is:

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"ModifiedBy","op":"eq","data":"Somedata"}]}
```

Notice it is missing the type attribute. Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on "Refresh" button the value of the `filters` parameter which should be send to the server should be

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[]}
```

If you has another values you should post the code of the grid and describe the use case. If one could reproduce your problem one can either find a bug in jqGrid or in your program.

Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: Sorry I was not specific when I said the refresh button. It is not the refresh button on the browser but the refresh button on the jqgrid. I am currently using jqgrid 4.1.

Comment: @PCG: Do you mean [jqGrid 4.1.2](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) or you use some commercial product from http://www.trirand.net/ which is based on jqGrid (like jqSuite for ASP.NET v4.1.0.0)?

Comment: I was using 4.1.0 but just upgraded to 4.1.2 and I still see the problem.

Comment: @PCG: I have never seen `"type":"text"` inside of `rules`. It should not exist at all. Could you post an example which reproduce the problem? Could you describe the test case exactly. For example I don't understand what you mean under the "refresh button". Is it "Reload Grid" button in the navigation bar or "Reset" button in the [Advance Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) dialog? Which kind of [searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#searching) you use in your experiments (searching toolbar, advanced searching...)?

Comment: Darn, I am new to jqgrid and didn't realize that we added to the filter on the beforeSearch event, since that event is not being called when clicking the reload button in the jqgrid we had to add to the filter on the beforeClear event as well.....Thanks for helping @Oleg